# Run Cypher query exactly N times

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Is there a way to repeat a Cypher query exactly N times? Either in the web interface or console.

There are APOC procedures to run a query until it returns zero. But I did not find anything to run a query multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the APOC procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`:

The docs about `apoc.periodic.iterate` says:

> With `apoc.periodic.iterate` you provide 2 statements, the first outer
>   statement is providing a stream of values to be processed. The second,
>   inner statement processes one element at a time (...)

In the below example, the first statement is returning 10 elements. This way, the second statement will be executed 10 times, producing 10 `:Person` nodes.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "WITH RANGE(0,9) AS list UNWIND list as element RETURN element",
    "CREATE(:Person)", {}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to involve APOC currently you can just do as follows:

```
UNWIND range(0,500) as iterations
CREATE(:Person);
```